# How can I find out the git branch my current branch is based on?

Tags: git, branch

This might be a simple question (maybe asked before?), but I haven't been able to find an answer (I really tried, I'm not just lazy :) ).

I am working on a git branch that is based on another branch. However, I don't know which branch it is based on.

Is there a command or a way to find out which branch my current branch originates from?

I tried looking in SourceTree and also with `git log --graph --all` but somehow I can't really figure out the originating point when the branch was created.

Thanks!

Comment: to clarify: I didnt create the branch I'm working on myself, but want to merge changes from the "parent" branch into my branch

Comment: How would you manually identify this branch?  You should consider the case where the original branch has additional commits after you branched off it.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen sorry, I probably wasnt very clear. I meant that. I am on a e.g. a feature branch "f1" branched off of e.g. master and want to continuously merge in changes from master. Except in my case, I dont know where "f1" was created off of. Alas, torek's answer seems to clear up a lot for me. Thanks!

Comment: You need to clarify to yourself exactly what you want to know, otherwise you cannot ask the machine to do it for you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There really is no such notion in git in the first place.

This is perhaps best seen by example.  Consider the following commit graph fragment:

```
        o    <-- branchA
       /
o--o--o
    \
     o--o    <-- branchB
```

Here, "obviously" `branchB` comes from `branchA`.  But wait, there's more, there's a bit I left out:

```
        o    <-- branchA
       /
o--o--o--o   <-- branchC
    \
     o--o    <-- branchB
```

Now, does `branchB` comes off `branchA` or does it come off `branchC`?

The trickiest part is that any of these branches can be created in *any* order;<sup>1</sup> and furthermore, the labels—the branch names—can also be moved or removed *at any time*.<sup>2</sup>  So if you decide that `branchB` is "based off" `branchA`, but then someone deletes `branchA` entirely, you're left with this:

```
o--o--o--o   <-- branchC
    \
     o--o    <-- branchB
```

and now `branchB` is clearly based off `branchC`, not `branchA`.

[**Edit**: if you want to identify the specific *commit* where two branches first "split apart", use [`git merge-base`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base).  Having found that commit, you can see what other branch names might also be interesting with `git branch --contains`, and so on.  The general rule here is that the commit *graph* is all you really have: labels like branch names are only good until you or someone else changes them later.  Tag labels should generally stay where they are but even those *can* be moved, it's just generally more of a pain.]

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, almost any: the parent commit(s) of a new commit must exist before you can create the child commits, unless you have a way of breaking the SHA-1 crypographic hash.

<sup>2</sup>Removing a label means that the commits found by starting at that label and working "backwards" (left-ward, and maybe up or down as well as long as you keep moving leftward) in these drawings) become "unreachable", unless they're found by starting from some other label.  Unreachable commits in the commit-graph are eventually<sup>3</sup> removed entirely, but typically you have about 30 days to get them back.

<sup>3</sup>This is achieved with git's "reflogs".  Each reflog entry works like a regular label, in terms of making a commit "reachable" and therefore retaining it.  It's actually the reflog entries that are expired.

Comment: I think that clears up enough for me to pursue this further. Git is one of those things that somehow dont become easier the more you learn about them ;)  
Thanks! :)

Comment: This is a really well rounded answer. Thank you!

Comment: There is always exactly one branch that is used for branching off - there is no ambiguity in that. If it was local, you can use reflog. Otherwise, just say that git does not store this info.

Answer (score 2):

If git-gc(1) hasn't kicked in and removed the information, create a shell script in your $PATH, name it `git-fork-point` with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -gt 0 ]
then
    target="$1"
else
    target=$(git branch|sed -ne 's,^\* ,,p')
fi

git reflog |sed -nE \
    "s,^([a-f0-9]+).*: checkout: moving from ([^[:space:]]+) to ${target}\$,Forked on commit \1 from \2.,p" |tail -1
```

It's now useable as git fork-point and defaults to current branch.

This is based on the assumption, that the first occurence of a branch name associated with a checkout, creates a new branch (reflog is in reverse chronological, hence the tail -1).

There's two things wrong with that:

- re-use of branch name after discovering one used the wrong parent, indeed lists the wrong parent
- if history is missing this just lists the first time the switch is made.

It works for 80% case though, which is why I use it.